# MODIFY_PHONE_STATE permission required for endCall on Oreo

Tags: android, android-permissions

I made an app to block some incoming calls. The app seems running well and done the job.
But recently I tried on an android 8.0 phone and crashed.

```
java.lang.SecurityException: MODIFY_PHONE_STATE permission required.
at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2005)
at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1951)
at com.android.internal.telephony.ITelephony$Stub$Proxy.endCall(ITelephony.java:2027)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at anywheresoftware.b4a.agraham.reflection.Reflection.runmethod(Reflection.java:216)
at anywheresoftware.b4a.agraham.reflection.Reflection.RunMethod(Reflection.java:802)
```

So seems the MODIFY_PHONE_STATE permission is required on android 8.0.

I tried to add the permission on the manifest or asking on runtime. No luck.

```
@Override
        public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
            switch (state) {
                case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:
                    numberGlobal = incomingNumber;

                    //Turn ON the mute in case we have to block the call)
                    AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
                    audioManager.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_RING, true);

                    if (hasToBeBlocked()) {
                        try {
                            Method method =  telephonyManager.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("getITelephony");
                            method.setAccessible(true);   // true

                            telephonyService = (ITelephony) method.invoke(telephonyManager);
                            telephonyService.silenceRinger();
                            telephonyService.endCall();  // Crashes here only on android 8.0
                            showToast("Ending Call");
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                                     Toast.makeText(context, "AQUI: " + e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    }

                    //Turn OFF the mute
                    audioManager.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_RING, false);

                    break;
                case PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE:
                    break;
            }
            super.onCallStateChanged(state, incomingNumber);
        }
```

So what can I do to end a call on android 8.0 (and up)?

Answer (score 1):

As per the [`MODIFY_PHONE_STATE` documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission#MODIFY_PHONE_STATE):

> Not for use by third-party applications.

Therefore your app cannot receive this permission.

As per the [`endCall` documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telecom/TelecomManager.html#endCall()):

> Companion apps for wearable devices should use the [`InCallService`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telecom/InCallService.html) API instead. Apps performing call screening should use the [`CallScreeningService`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telecom/CallScreeningService.html) API instead.

As per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43617497/can-a-third-party-app-implement-callscreeningservice-in-android-7), these were both limited to only the default dialer app until Android Q, where now third party apps can request that role.

Comment: You can get it for a personal app if you're willing to root your device and make your app a system app.  It just won't work as a play store app