# Ending a phone call in Android API level 30

Tags: android, android-studio, android-permissions

I would like to be able to close the phone call when it rings but from what I read ITELEPHONY is only valid for API level <28.
Is there another way I can block the phone call?
Below is my code and I get
`Accessing hidden method Landroid/telephony/TelephonyManager;->getITelephony()Lcom/android/internal/telephony/ITelephony; (greylist-max-p, reflection, denied) 2021-04-28 16:55:41.884 18265-18265/com.example.myapplication W/System.err: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: android.telephony.TelephonyManager.getITelephony []`

I looked for other solutions already posted on stackoverflow but none worked. In the manifest I have added the following permissions: ANSWER_PHONE_CALLS, READ_PHONE_STATE, CALL_PHONE, READ_CALL_LOG.

I forgot to mention that I also have the ITelephony interface with the specific package com.android.internal.telephony;

```
public class MyPhoneReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        TelephonyManager telephony;
        telephony = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        MyPhoneStateListener listener = new MyPhoneStateListener(context);
        telephony.listen(listener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
    }


    public static class MyPhoneStateListener extends PhoneStateListener {
        Context context;
        public MyPhoneStateListener(Context context) {
            super();
            this.context = context;
        }

        @Override
        public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String callingNumber){
            super.onCallStateChanged(state, callingNumber);
            if((state == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK) || (state == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING))
            {

                Log.d("CALLING",callingNumber);
                BlockTheCall(callingNumber);

            }
        }

        private void BlockTheCall(String callingNumber)
        {
            Log.d("CALLING",callingNumber);
            try{

                TelephonyManager tm;
                tm = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
                Class c = Class.forName(tm.getClass().getName());
                Method m = c.getDeclaredMethod("getITelephony");
                m.setAccessible(true);
                com.android.internal.telephony.ITelephony telephonyService = (ITelephony) m.invoke(tm);
                telephonyService.silenceRinger();
                telephonyService.endCall();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Perhaps you're looking for [Can a third-party app implement CallScreeningService in android 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43617497/can-a-third-party-app-implement-callscreeningservice-in-android-7)